# Taking the union of two queries in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Suppose I'm making a blog site where users can make posts and follow other users. I want to have a single ActiveRecord relation for the posts by a user and all the people that user is following. I can do it as a ruby method, and I've called it `posts_by_me_and_people_i_am_following` in the `User` class below. Is there a way of making this out of pure ActiveRecord?

```
class User
    has_many :posts
    has_many :follows
    has_many :followed_users, through: follows, source: :target_user

    has_many :posts_by_followed_users, through: :followed_users, source: :posts

    # I want this to be an ActiveRecord::Relation so that I can filter or order it
    def posts_by_me_and_people_i_am_following
        posts.to_a + posts_by_followed_users.to_a
    end
end

class Post
    belongs_to: :user
end

class Follow
    belongs_to :target_user, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :source_user, class_name: "User"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for [ARel](http://github.com/rails/arel).

```
def posts_by_me_and_people_i_am_following
  t = Post.arel_table
  results=Post.where(
    t[:user_id].eq(self.id).
    or(t[:user_id].in(self.followed_user_ids))
  )
end
```